# Cassandra Read consistency

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra, eventual-consistency

In my use case for cassandra writes are followed by reads and we are observing stale reads from cassandra. I understand that in cassandra read consistency is tough to achieve but what are alternates, how do we know read is stale? As long as I can know that read is stale and writes are still catching up, I should be good, what I can't afford is to return stale data.

Looking for spring boot and spring data cassandra based solution

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're using a low consistency of `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE` which is why you're running into this problem. I would argue that this statement is incorrect:

> I understand that in cassandra read consistency is tough to achieve...

Consistency is very easy to achieve even in Cassandra's *eventually consistent* architecture if you follow the recommended guidelines.

In almost all cases, you should use `LOCAL_QUORUM` for both reads and writes. As a general recommendation, the read consistency plus write consistency *must be greater than* the replication factor:

```
    read_CL + write_CL > replication_factor
```

There are very limited edge cases where low consistencies such as `ONE` and `LOCAL_ONE` are appropriate. Cheers!